# Is there a way to not stop the transition when the tab is inactive?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a carousel but I found the problem that every time I switch tabs and return, the animations are delayed, is there a way to solve this?

I tried to do something with the page visibility API, but couldn't fix it.

[image: Image from Gyazo]

My code:

```
"use strict";
class Carousel {
    constructor(_options) {
        this.images = [];
        this.imgIndex = 1;
        this.transitionStatus = null;
        this.options = {
            autoplay: {
                enabled: true,
                speed: 5000
            },
            speed: 5000
        };
        this.nextQueue = 0;
        //config options
        Object.assign(this.options, _options);
        //set props
        this.container = document.getElementsByClassName("carousel__container")[0];
        this.itemsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("carousel__items")[0];
        //get imgs from carousel items and remove #text's childs
        document.querySelectorAll(".carousel__item").forEach(item => {
            item.childNodes.forEach((child) => child.nodeName === "IMG" ? this.images.push(child) : false);
        });
        this.setup();
    }
    setup() {

        //add class to all images in carouselContainer
        for (let index = 0; index < this.images.length; index++) {
            const image = this.images[index];
            image === null || image === void 0 ? void 0 : image.classList.add('carousel__itemImg'); /* img */
        }
        const toContainerFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

        // create span index image counter
        this.spanIndex = document.createElement('span');
        this.spanIndex.classList.add('container__number'); //imgIndex
        this.updateIndexContent();
        toContainerFragment.appendChild(this.spanIndex);

        //create next prev arrows
        const arrowNext = document.createElement("span");
        arrowNext.id = "carousel_next";
        arrowNext.textContent = "=>";
        toContainerFragment.appendChild(arrowNext);
        const arrowPrev = document.createElement("span");
        arrowPrev.id = "carousel_prev";
        arrowPrev.textContent = "<=";
        toContainerFragment.appendChild(arrowPrev);
        arrowNext.addEventListener("click", () => this.next());
        arrowPrev.addEventListener("click", () => this.prev());
        
        //add arrows and span index to container
        this.container.appendChild(toContainerFragment);
        //autoplay
        if (this.options.autoplay.enabled) {
            this.autoPlay();
        }
    }
    next() {
        if (this.imgIndex == this.images.length) {
            this.imgIndex = 0;
        }

        if (this.transitionStatus == "started") {
            this.nextQueue++;
            return;
        }

        const clientWidth = this.container.clientWidth;
        this.imgIndex++;
        this.updateIndexContent();

        this.itemsContainer.style.transition = `transform ${this.options.speed}ms linear`;
        this.itemsContainer.style.transform = `translateX(-${clientWidth}px)`;
        this.transitionStatus = "started";

        const transitionEndEvent = () => {
            this.itemsContainer.removeEventListener("transitionend", transitionEndEvent);
            this.itemsContainer.style.transition = "";
            this.itemsContainer.style.transform = `translateX(-${0}px)`;
            const previousElement = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel__item")[0];
            this.itemsContainer.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", previousElement);
            this.transitionStatus = "ended";
            if (this.nextQueue) {
                this.nextQueue--;
                this.next();
            }
        };
        this.itemsContainer.addEventListener("transitionend", transitionEndEvent);



        let currentTranslateX;
        document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
            if (document.hidden) {
                const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(this.itemsContainer);
                var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(computedStyle.transform);
                currentTranslateX = matrix.m41;
            }
            else {
                console.log(clientWidth);
                console.log(currentTranslateX);
                const resume = clientWidth + currentTranslateX;
                console.log(resume);
            }
        });
    }

    updateIndexContent() {
        this.spanIndex.textContent = `${this.imgIndex} / ${this.images.length}`;
    }

    autoPlay() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.next();
        }, this.options.autoplay.speed);
    }
}
const carousel = new Carousel({
    autoplay: {
        enabled: false,
        speed: 1000
    },
    speed: 5000
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="carousel__container">
      <div class="carousel__items">
        <div class="carousel__item">
          <img src="../assets/1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel__item">
          <img src="../assets/2.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel__item">
          <img src="../assets/3.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="./main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

IGNORE: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Please don’t evade the quality checks and actually take the advice into consideration.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think there is much more to explain.

Comment: Probably not, browsers tend to put things on hold when the tab isn't visible.

Answer (score 1):

Timers are throttled when the page is not visible.  You'll need your code to not rely on them.

The easiest solution in your specific case is to switch to CSS animations.  While these animations are also subject to throttling, at least they're managed by the browser for you.  When the user switches back to the tab, the browser should handle the updates for you.

Comment: And there is no way to do it in javascript? The problem is that I would also like to pass the transform option through the parameters

Comment: @Franco You can do it in JavaScript, but you'll have to then pre-calculate at which time your animation should land and where.  Then, use `requestAnimationFrame()` to handle placing things correctly.  (This is the best method anyway, if you're using JS to do this, even if you didn't have the throttling problem.)

Comment: I tried to use requestAnimationFrame () before but it was very difficult to calculate the animation and I abandoned that idea, tomorrow I will try again, if you have an example of requestAnimationFrame it would be very useful, thanks anyway!